# HuggingFace: Streaming dataset from local dir using custom data_loader and data_collator

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets

I have custom data_loader and data_collator that I am using for training in Transformer model using HuggingFace API. It also does the mapping of dataset where tokenization is also done.
My data_loader script is a classes that inherents `datasets.GeneratorBasedBuilder` so contains `_generate_examples` function to yield samples.

Upon starting the training, it caches whole dataset (only once on a system), then starts the training. I can reuse that cache on local system but can't use that cached `.arrow` file on any other system, therefore the caching process restarts. I wanna avoid caching by using streaming feature. My current codes looks like:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset ("/../my_data_loader.py", streaming =True)
train_dataset = dataset["train"]
train_datatset = train_dataset.map (..... )
data_collator = MyDataCollaor (......)
...
...
trainer = Trainer (model=model, arg= training_arg, train_dataset=train_dataset, data_collaor...)
```

Note: I don't where I have to code: `__len__` and `__iter__` functions on my side.

Answer (score 0):

Using datasets of version 1.12 or above, we can stream dataset (without caching) by setting `streaming =True` as follows.

```
 dataset = load_dataset ("/../my_data_loader.py", streaming =True)
```

In this case, the dataset would be Iterable dataset, hence `mapping` would also be little different. Let say following script was using in `caching` mode:

```
train_dataset = datasets["train"]
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(
            tokenize_and_align_labels,
            batched=True,
            remove_columns=remove_columns,
            num_proc= preprocessing_num_workers,
            load_from_cache_file= not overwrite_cache,
        )
```

Then after turning on streaming, you have convert dataset format and change parameters of mapping function as well.

```
train_dataset = datasets["train"]
train_dataset = train_dataset.with_format("torch")
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(
        tokenize_and_align_labels,
        batched=True,
         )
```